# Speeding up a linked list?

Tags: java, optimization, linked-list

I'm a student and fairly new to Java.  I was looking over the different speeds achieved by the two collections in Java, Linked List, and ArrayList.  I know that an ArrayList is much much faster at looking up and placing in values into its indexes.  My question is:

how can one make a linked list faster, if at all possible?

Thanks for any help.

zmahir

Comment: "Faster" at what? In what way do you measure speed? Please make this question more specific. Explain, perhaps, how you're planning to use the linked list in question.

Comment: I see, to be more specific, there's no way to speed up a linked list's lookup and insert times correct?  From say O(n) to something faster?

Comment: I think you have enough to go on now. ArrayLists and LinkedLists have pros and cons. In theory, ArrayList has faster access and slower insertion (not so relevant if you don't insert in the middle of the list) while LinkedLists have faster insertion but slower access. However, there's a section in [Java Performance Tuning](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000158.do) - published 2003 - that indicates that the ArrayList insertion speed was relatively insignificant. Things should only have improved since but who knows. Sorry can't point you to right page, I've locked myself out of Safari!

Answer (score 9):

When talking about speed, perhaps you mean [complexity](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory). Insertion and retrieval operations for `ArrayList` (and arrays) are O(1), while for `LinkedList` they are O(n). And this cannot be changed - it is 'by definition'.

O(n) means that in order to insert an object at a given position, or retrieve it, you must traverse, in the worst case, all (n) the items in the list. Hence n operations. For ArrayList this is only one operation.

Comment: Insertion is only O(1) for ArrayList if you're inserting at the end. For the middle, it's O(n), with a larger constant than the O(n) for LinkedList. (It's faster to iterate to find the middle of the list than it is to move the second half of the list down one spot in the array.)

Comment: One theoretical operation, that is. In practice, to insert an item in a linked list, you only need to allocate a small piece of memory and change the links of the previous and next items, while for an array you need to reallocate the whole array, move the upper part and write the new value to the open space. However, theoretically you're right, and in practice, a lot of the operation I described is hidden from the user (the programmer) and is highly optimized.

Comment: @David Yaw - if the backing array has an ensured capacity, then insertion is O(n). That is what I meant. @GolezTrol - yes, LinkedList is more memory efficient.

Comment: @David Yaw - *"It's faster to iterate to find the middle of the list than it is to move the second half of the list down one spot in the array."*.  Not necessarily.  If the nodes of the linked list are scattered over many virtual memory pages, it might be a lot slower.

Answer (score 2):

You probably can't. You don't know the size (well, ok you can), nor the location of each element. To find element 100 in a linked list, you need to start with item 1, find it's link to item 2, etc. until you find 100. This makes inserting into this list a tedious job.

There are many alternatives depending on your exact goals. You can use b-trees or similar methods to split the large linked list into smaller ones. Or use hashlists if you want to quickly find items. Or use simple arrays. But if you want a list that performs like an ArrayList, why not use an ArrayList?

Answer (score 1):

You can split off regions which are linked to the main linked list, so this gives you entry points directly inside the list so you don't have to walk up to them. See the `subList` method here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html. This is useful if you have a number of 'sentences' made out of words, say. You can use a separate linked list to iterate over the sentences, which are sublists of the main linked list.

You can also use a `ListIterator` when adding, removing, or accessing elements. This helps greatly with increasing the speed of sequential access. See the `listIterator` method for this, and the class: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html.

Comment: This is by far the best answer and should be marked as such.

Answer (score 1):

Speed of a linked list could be improved by using skip lists: http://igoro.com/archive/skip-lists-are-fascinating/

Answer (score 0):

a linked list uses pointers to walk through the items, so for example if you asked for the 5th item, the runtime will start from the first item and walks through each pointer until it reaches the 5th item.

there is really not much you can do about it.  a linked list may not be a good choice if you need fast acces to items. although there are some optimizations for it such as creating a circular linked list or a double linked list where you can walk back and forth the list but this really depends on the business logic and the application requirements.

my advise is to avoid linked lists if it does not match your needs and changing to a different data structure might be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, data structures are designed to do certain things well. LinkedLists are designed to be faster than ArrayLists at inserting elements and removing elements and about the same as ArrayLists at iterating across the list in order. When you change the way a LinkedList works, you make it no longer a true LinkedList, so there's not really any way to modify them to be faster at something and still be a LinkedList.

You'll need to examine the way you're using this particular collection and decide whether a LinkedList is really the best data structure for your purposes. If you share with us how you're using it, and why you need it to be faster, then we can advise you on which data structure you ought to consider using.

Comment: I just  got off an interview phone call. The task was to implement a program which receives n chars as input and keep the order for later printing. Additionally, it has a method that receives an index range and removes that range from the list. This is Linked List optimization question since there are complexity demands as well. The answer contained an additional Linked List with pointers in certain intervals, created in the time of insertion. For this task, can a better data structure be used?

Comment: Based on what you've said, that's a pretty good data structure for the task. I could also envision a tree structure being a good fit, ensuring the complexity stays at `O(log n)`. Finding the optimal solution would depend on knowing the specific frequency of each operation and such. But it's all theoretical anyway, since even a very suboptimal implementation could probably complete millions of operations in the time it takes to actually print a single page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You might have missed `keep the order for later printing`. I think a tree is not suitable for that, unless every node in the tree keeps a singular child node, giving us a linked list. Is my statement correct or have I missed something? Thanks again.

Comment: @Nom1fan: There are tree structures like [B-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) that maintain ordering in a way that adding and removing values is an `O(log n)` operation (rather than `O(n)` like in a linked list). I imagine it's similar to the "Linked list with pointers in certain intervals" idea, but probably more scalable because the intervals scale with the size of the collection.

Comment: B-trees are designed to keep ordering based on the values of the inserted items. It should be easy enough to adapt a B-tree to this case just by comparing the inserted values based on something like the order in which they were added. But since you don't have the requirement to add new items in the middle of the tree, you could potentially come up with a more customized balanced tree structure that treats indexes as a first-class concept. Again, this is largely academic because the time taken to print will be several orders of magnitude greater than time taken to manipulate the collection.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed responses! All is clear except for: `treats indexes as a first-class concept` which I do not understand. What is treating as a first-class concept? Thanks again.

Comment: I failed to mention another constraint in my original task. insertion in O(1) time. That's why I went with "Linked list with pointers in certain intervals"

Comment: "Treats indexes as first-class concepts" meaning I don't know if typical B-tree implementations can be told "find (or remove) the item at index `n`". They're more concerned with maintaining order and allowing in-order insertion and traversal. You may have to tweak a basic B-tree implementation to support quickly finding a given index instead of seeking solely based on values. But given your other requirement, it doesn't matter: you can't maintain a balanced tree structure with O(1) insertion time.

Comment: It's clear the interviewers were going for Linked List. Interval-based pointers are a cute optimization. On the one hand, it doesn't change the big-O complexity: given a large enough number of items to remove, you'll find the performance is still tied to an `O(n)` trajectory. On the other hand, it doesn't take a big-O improvement to see practical benefits: a 100x decrease in time taken is often enough. On the gripping hand, this is still a premature optimization: You could add and remove millions of elements from a LinkedList (or ArrayList) in the time it takes to print a single page.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people smarter than you or I have looked at the implementation of the Java collection classes. If there were an optimization to be made, they would have found it and already made it.

Since the collection classes are pretty much as optimized as they can be, our primary task should be to choose the correct one.

When choosing your collection type, don't forget about things like HashSet. If order doesn't matter, and you don't need to put duplicates in the collection, then HashSet may be appropriate.

Comment: -1 for 'smarter than you', you have no idea how smart he is or the people that 'had a look' at the collection frameworks are. Answers of this type are extremely unprofessional and do not help at all.

Comment: Perhaps my phrasing could have been better. The point is that the collection classes are some of the most-used classes in the Java library, and it is not an unreasonable assumption to say that Sun has had them well profiled and inspected by optimization experts, and that if there were a way to make LinkedList faster, that could be explained and implemented by someone who is, as he said, a student fairly new to Java, it would have already been done. His primary task should be to select from the available collection classes, not to modify them.

Comment: "Oh, let me not think about this problem, because if is a solution someone else would have found it". With that attitude there wouldn't be much improvement. :) And even if he doesn't find a way to speed things up, at least he found out why, so it seems a fairly legitimate question to me.

Comment: I think that the best think he can do is to delve into topics that interest him the most. If he is interested in Java there is no way he's not going to go deep into the collections framework. I would actually encourage him to try and optimize them, that would be a great way to deepen his knowledge !

Comment: Agreed, delving into the collections framework is a great way to increase one's knowledge. I always like to have a copy of the library source on my system, be it .Net or Java. As a student, I'd encourage him to get a copy of the source, and see how the various collection classes are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm a student and fairly new to Java. ...  how can one make a linked list faster, if at all possible?

The standard Java collection type (indeed all data structures implemented in any language!) represent compromises on various "measures" such as:

- The amount of memory needed to represent the data structure.
- The time taken to perform various operations; e.g. for a "list" the operations of interest are insertion, removal, indexing, contains, iteration and so on.
- How easy or hard it is to integrate / reuse the collection type; see below.

So for instance:

- ArrayList offers lower memory overheads, fast indexing (O(1)), but slow contains, random insertion and removal (O(N)).
- LinkedList has higher memory overheads, slow indexing and contains (O(N)), but faster  removal (O(1)) *under certain circumstances*.

The various performance measures are *typically* determines by the maths of the various data structures.  For example, if you have a chain of nodes, the only way to get the `ith` node is to step through them from the beginning.  This involves following `i` pointers.

Sometimes you can modify the data structures to improve one aspect of the performance.  But this typically comes at the cost of some other aspect of the performance.  (For example, you could add a separate index to make indexing of a linked list faster.  But the cost of maintaining the index on insertion / deletion would mean that you'd probably be better of using an `ArrayList`.)

In some cases the integration / reuse requirements have significant impact on performance.

For example, it is theoretically possible to optimize a linked list's space usage by adding a `next` field to the list element type, combining the element and node objects and saving 16 or so bytes per list entry.  However, this would make the list type less general (the member/element class would need to implement a specific interface), and has the restriction that an element can belong to at most one list at any time.  These restrictions are so limiting that this approach is rarely used in Java.

For a second example, consider the problem of inserting at a given position in a linked list.  For the `LinkedList` class, this is normally an `O(N)` operation, because you have to step through the list to find the position.  In theory, if an application could find and remember a position, it should be able to perform the insertion at that position in `O(1)`.  Unfortunately, neither the `List` APIs provides no way to "remember" a position.

While neither of these examples is a fundamental roadblock to a developer "doing his own thing", they illustrate that using general data structure APIs and general implementations of those APIs has performance implications, and therefore represents a trade-off between performance and ease-of-use.